# Zxing feature (Image within device)

Tags: android, image, device, zxing

i have a question regarding Zxing. I have immplemented succesfully the barcode scanner and its working better than expected.

My question is:

It is possible to scan a barcode from an image WITHIN the device (Internal or SD)?

If so, how can i achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Barcode Scanner does not do this, no. However Barcode Scanner+ does; it's one of the extra features I put into it.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android